# Need help to redirect the form on submit

Tags: javascript, html, drupal

I need help. When I submit this form I want it to automatically redirect to the value option (which is url) in the select list.

So on pressing submit for Ahmedabad selected in select list it should redirect to http://intranet.guj.nic.in/passport

Currently it is not redirecting. **What is the best way to do it using inline javascript code?**

```
<html><body>
<form  id="pass-form" >
<select id="pass-dropdown" ><option selected="selected">Select Passport Office
for Status page </option><option value="http://intranet.guj.nic.in/passport/">Ahemadabad
</option><option value="http://passportstatus.nic.in/passmain.php?city=asr">Amritsar
</option><option value="http://rpobangalore.gov.in/npassport.asp">Bangalore
</option><option value="http://passportstatus.nic.in/passmain.php?city=bly">Bareilly
</option></select>
<input type="submit"  onsubmit="var sel = document.getElementById('pass-dropdown'); window.location = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to check out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript and
http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-

Comment: Also why don't you just use links instead of the drop down list? Alternatively you could do this via a server side script. Just set headers to equal $_GET['form'].

Comment: Because the form has been submitted, the `window.location` will not fire.  You need to prevent the default submission behaviour, or handle it on the server side.  Something like `<?php if (isset($_POST['pass-dropdown']) && $_POST['pass-dropdown']) header('Location: ' . $_POST['pass-dropdown']);exit(); ?>` Should do the job.

Comment: @Sam I don't want Google to know where I'm redirecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**onsubmit** is an event of the `<form>` element and not of the submit button.

Change your form code to:

```
<form id="pass-form" onsubmit="window.location.href = 'newlocation'; return false;">
...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: but this way it won't redirect.

Comment: It will by putting the redirection code in onsubmit and returning false.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you might have to use `return` to ensure the desired return value gets used:

```
<form onsubmit="return redirectMe();">
  <input placeholder="Search" type="text">
</form>

... more code here ...

function redirectMe() {
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  return false;
}
```

Source: [How to pass an event object to a function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276870/how-to-pass-an-event-object-to-a-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `type = "submit"` to button

```
<input type="button" onclick="var sel = document.getElementById('pass-dropdown'); window.location = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value" />
```

*Update*

```
<input type="button" onclick="var sel = document.getElementById('pass-dropdown'); 
       var frm = document.getElementById("pass-form"); frm.action = sel; frm.submit();" />
```

It would be better if you put that in a function and call the function instead

Comment: Thanks but I want to keep type="submit" is it possible to change the ACTION in form and submit it then in the same way?

Comment: Yes. `frm = document.getElementById("pass-form"); frm.action = sel; frm.submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  id="pass-form" onsubmit="var sel = document.getElementById('pass-dropdown'); window.location = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value" >
    ...
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You must do the submit attribute to the form tag. Then it should work.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp

Comment: Use `window.location.replace(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)` instead of `window.loaction = ...` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp