# Calling a method with input instead of button

Tags: javascript, methods

hi have this method in JS:

This one is for the button im using till now.

```
 $('#balpha').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (alphasw < 1) { alphasw = 1;} 
    else { alphasw = 0;}
    $('.alpha').each(function(){
      /* element specific data object*/
      var data= $(this).data('maphilight') ;
        if (alphasw < 1) {
            data.alwaysOn = true;}
        else{
            data.alwaysOn = false;}
        $(this).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight')
       });
      });
```

For some reason i have to make the same call with a input type="image" so I add onClick="alphabutton();" on input propertis and did next changes in the method.

```
function alphabutton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (alphasw < 1) { alphasw = 1;} 
    else { alphasw = 0;}
    $('.alpha').each(function(){
      /* element specific data object*/
      var data= $(this).data('maphilight') ;
        if (alphasw < 1) {
            data.alwaysOn = true;}
        else{
            data.alwaysOn = false;}
        $(this).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight')
       });
    }
```

I cant see what is wrong, any advice?

I found a solution for my problem, probably I tried to make the things harder.

```
<input type="image" src="img/Buttons/alpha.png" id="balpha"/>
```

I just added id to the input tag, so I dont have to modify the first method.

Comment: You miss event argument here: onClick="alphabutton();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to use the jQuery [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#balpha, input[type=image]').click(function () {
    // Stuff here
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ok0mmu4k/)

Answer (score 0):

with

```
<input  type="image" onClick="alphabutton();"  />
```

you are getting error below line

```
    function alphabutton(e) {
       e.preventDefault();//error on this line
    }
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231396/492258) 
your code goes to:

```
 <input  type="image" onClick="alphabutton(event);"  />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLuvzvqj/)

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the handler with jquery `.click` or `.on` as you did before and then you will have access to event parameter.

Another option is to return false at the end of your element onclick handler. (just native javascript)