# javascript and this.value of radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I try to get the value of the checked radio button by javascript.

`<input value="3" type="RADIO" name="ME"  onclick="go_to_url ( 'OPT3' , this.value );">`

But JS does not give me any value even the event is where the button is?

Why?
How can I get the value of the clicked radio button in a way I do not have to change the function?

Comment: Consider not using the `onclick` attribute and use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an event object to a function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276870/how-to-pass-an-event-object-to-a-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has no problem.
Check this out

```
<input value="3" type="radio" name="ME" onclick="go_to_url( 'OPT3' , this.value );">

function go_to_url(label, value) {
    console.log(label);
    console.log(value);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7gkesxo/

Comment: Thank you so much. I now found the bug ... in the div above ... onclick there.

Answer (score 1):

Use for your button an `id` then you can use `document.getElementById` to get your element and `addEventListener` to add an `click`-event. The on-click in your HTML delete.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<input value="3" id='btn' type="RADIO" name="ME">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
    go_to_url('OPT3' , this.value);
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Yeah I know but I was in a hurry and wanted to finish the number of answers I planned to give @MarkRotteveel