# How to stop refresh after AJAX to Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I have a modal where a user can add a new `Category`. When the user adds a new `Category` and receives a response from the AJAX request I would like to use the response data to update some of the existing page data. Problem is that my form is not allowing `e.preventDefault()` but rather just refreshing the page after it receives a response:

JQuery AJAX:

```
function addCategory(e) {
    let post_url = '{% url "policies-categories-form" %}'
    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type:'POST',
        data: $('#addCategoryForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            // document.getElementById('editCategoriesContainer').innerHTML = data;
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Error');
        },
    });
};
```

Form (which is loaded using JQuery, only after a user clicks a button:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!--Add new category form-->
<div class="form-row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        {{ form.title|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        {{ form.parent|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        {{ form.groups|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row mt-4 mb-4">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block"
                id="addCategoryBtn"
                onclick="addCategory(this)"
                type="submit">
            <span class="fas fa-plus"></span> Add Category
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
@login_required
def policies_categories_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = PoliciesCategoryForm(request.POST, company=request.tenant)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            categories = PoliciesAndProceduresCategory.objects.exclude(parent__isnull=False).values()
            return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'categories': list(categories)})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False, 'error': form.errors})
    else:
        form = PoliciesCategoryForm(company=request.tenant)
        context = {'form': form}
        template = 'policies/policies_categories_form.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
```

How do I stop it from refreshing the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Easy fix : change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276870/how-to-pass-an-event-object-to-a-function-in-javascript) way.

Comment: add
 e..preventDefault(); in addCategory() function at the top.

Comment: I did. did not work. Button needed to be changed as @Swati stated. then I also changed it to : `onclick="addCategory(event)"` and all is well. Thanks!